# SQL Trace - to monitor activity of individual table

Tags: sql-server

I want to record activity (insert/update/delete) happening on a individual table through SQL Trace. We don't want to use profiler. We want to capture what happens over a period 1-2 days to identify issues, as we don't know which process is updating that table (and that process is adding incorrect data)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Profiler, you could put a trigger on the table.

But Profiler would be better.